# Sequence number generation in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, docker

I need to generate a sequence number which is in ranges of 1000 to 3000. Every day at 12 midnight this sequence should reset to 1000 and for each request this should be incremented. Is there any way we can achieve this. I need to implementation in one of web application which uses Spring Boot and MongoDB.

I know in Java we cant achieve as my application will be run as multiple instance also it will be deployed in Cloud docker container.

Answer (score 1):

1) To generate the sequence number, you can have the sequence value stored in a Mongo document and use findAndModify operation to increment it everytime.  You might want to use the option that returns the modified document, to get the latest value. 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/

2) To reset the value at midnight, you can use spring boot scheduling. You can annotate the method which would reset the value in the mongo document with @Scheduled and specify a cron expression to run at the exact time.

Since the sequence is actually stored in the database, you should not be having issues with multiple instances of your application.